# Detecting formatted text in PDF Tables

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pdfplumber

I have some code that parses through tables in a PDF file and converts them to CSVs.

```
import csv
import pdfplumber

def process_my_PDF(pdf_path: str) -> {}:
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            tables = page.extract_tables()
            with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
                for table in tables:
                        for row in table:
                            print(row)
                            writer = csv.writer(file)
                            writer.writerow(row)

pdf_path = "/tmp/foo.pdf"
process_my_PDF(pdf_path=pdf_path)
```

The PDF also has bold, italicized and underlined text in the table's cells and I need to preserve that information in the resulting csv (I have a reader app that will render it) via html style markups around the text that I extract.

How do I detect the formatting in the table text?